# How to share one physical drive with many virtual machines?

Tags: hyper-v

Is it possible to share one physical drive (1 partition) with many virtual machines in Hyper-V at the same time?

If yes: how?

Comment: at the same time?

Comment: Why would you want to do this exactly?  Are we talking about an OS drive, or just a plain data drive? Why not just use an OS-level network share.

Comment: @Keltari yes - I've updated my question.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 mostly because one VM should perform as NAS and the other VM should add content (automatically) to the drive. But I don't want to stress the network with it.

Comment: If both VM's are on the same host, then use an "internal network" (ie: a Private Switch) for the VMs and the traffic will never leave the host machine.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Good thought. But: Both machines need external access (internet) too.

Comment: Machines can have more than one network interface. It's quite usual to put high speed links between servers that are separate from the one the clients use to access the servers. Consider the physical world. Would you use a "SATA splitter" to share a drive between two running machines? Why not?